# TKGm - disable Tanzu default storage class

Tags: tanzu-tkgm

I have TKGm 2.1 installed, but I use NetApp's Trident as the storage backend so I set up storage classes that utilize Trident.
However, I cannot make any of these classes the default without having Tanzu's builtin storage class revert to its default state.

I tried removing the `is-default-class` annotation, deleting the default storage class and even removing the vsphere-csi package from the management cluster - eventually the app came back, the storage class restored and the annotation became present again as if nothing happened...

How can I make Tanzu honor at least the removal of the annotation?